# Add markers to the start and end points of a path Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement some sought of custom directions service on Google maps. I have a bunch of pre-made paths that I hide and show depending on the selection from two drop-down boxes. So far it works great. However, I would like to add markers to the start and end of the paths, How do i go about doing it?

[image: A Path, I would like to add a marker to the start and end of the path.]

Here is a working sample http://jsfiddle.net/PwFDM/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <style type="text/css">
            html {
                height: 100%
            }
            body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0
            }
            #map_canvas {
                height: 100%
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD9W-wEHa5KzvcntFzGgyTwWtx4wvrs0os&sensor=true">

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div><strong>Start: </strong>

            <select id="start">
                <option>Building 1</option>
                <option>Building 2</option>
                <option>Building 3</option>
                <option>Building 4</option>
                <option>Building 5</option>
                <option>Building 6</option>
                <option>Building 7</option>
                <option>Building 8</option>
            </select> <strong>End:</strong> 
            <select id="end">
                <option>Building 1</option>
                <option>Building 2</option>
                <option>Building 3</option>
                <option>Building 4</option>
                <option>Building 5</option>
                <option>Building 6</option>
                <option>Building 7</option>
                <option>Building 8</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" onclick="drawDirections();" value="GO" />
        </div>
        <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var mapOptions = {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.507684, 0.063686),
                zoom: 17
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            // Predefine all the paths
            var paths = [];

            paths['1_to_2'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.508445, 0.063944),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507457, 0.064019)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['1_to_3'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.508445, 0.063944),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507494, 0.063399)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['1_to_4'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.508445, 0.063944),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507709, 0.063301)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['1_to_5'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.508445, 0.063944),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.50747, 0.062659),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507501, 0.062467)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['1_to_6'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.508445, 0.063944),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['1_to_7'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.508445, 0.063944),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['1_to_8'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.508445, 0.063944),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507248, 0.065797),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507449, 0.065805),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507442, 0.066004)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });

            //---------------------------------------------------------
            paths['2_to_3'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507457, 0.064019),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507494, 0.063399)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['2_to_4'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507457, 0.064019),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507709, 0.063301)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['2_to_5'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507457, 0.064019),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.50747, 0.062659),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507501, 0.062467)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['2_to_6'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507457, 0.064019),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['2_to_7'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507457, 0.064019),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['2_to_8'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507457, 0.064019),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507248, 0.065797),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507449, 0.065805),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507442, 0.066004)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });

            //---------------------------------------------------------
            paths['3_to_4'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507494, 0.063399),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507709, 0.063301)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['3_to_5'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507494, 0.063399),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.50747, 0.062659),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507501, 0.062467)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['3_to_6'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507494, 0.063399),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['3_to_7'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507494, 0.063399),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['3_to_8'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507494, 0.063399),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507248, 0.065797),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507449, 0.065805),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507442, 0.066004)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });

            //-------------------------------------------------------------
            paths['4_to_5'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507709, 0.063301),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.50747, 0.062659),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507501, 0.062467)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['4_to_6'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507709, 0.063301),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['4_to_7'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507709, 0.063301),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['4_to_8'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507709, 0.063301),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507474, 0.063877),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507248, 0.065797),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507449, 0.065805),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507442, 0.066004)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });

            //---------------------------------------------------------------
            paths['5_to_6'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507501, 0.062467),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.50747, 0.062659),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['5_to_7'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507501, 0.062467),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.50747, 0.062659),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['5_to_8'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507501, 0.062467),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.50747, 0.062659),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507248, 0.065797),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507449, 0.065805),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507442, 0.066004)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });

            //----------------------------------------------------
            paths['6_to_7'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });
            paths['6_to_8'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507248, 0.065797),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507449, 0.065805),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507442, 0.066004)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });

            //--------------------------------------------------------
            paths['7_to_8'] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507275, 0.062455),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507293, 0.062681),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507287, 0.063839),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507248, 0.065797),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507449, 0.065805),
                new google.maps.LatLng(51.507442, 0.066004)],
                strokeColor: '#FF0000'
            });

            function drawDirections() {
                var start = 1 + document.getElementById('start').selectedIndex;
                var end = 1 + document.getElementById('end').selectedIndex;
                var i;

                if (start === end) {
                    alert('Please choose different buildings');
                } else {
                    // Hide all polylines
                    for (i in paths) {
                        paths[i].setOptions({
                            map: null
                        });
                    }

                    // Show the route
                    if (typeof paths['' + start + '_to_' + end] !== 'undefined') {
                        paths['' + start + '_to_' + end].setOptions({
                            map: map
                        });
                    } else if (typeof paths['' + end + '_to_' + start] !== 'undefined') {
                        paths['' + end + '_to_' + start].setOptions({
                            map: map
                        });
                    }

                    var laLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507684, 0.063686);
                    map.panTo(laLatLng);
                    map.setZoom(17);
                    //panTo(latLng:LatLng)
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there a question?  [Example of adding custom markers to the start and end of routes](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html), creating and adding custom markers is also covered fairly well in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers)

Comment: I know how to add markers. What I want is to add markers to the start and end of the paths. Take a look at the example.

Comment: What issue are you having doing with doing that?  Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: [jsfiddle with 2 markers at each end of the path](http://jsfiddle.net/PwFDM/7/)

Comment: Thanks man. That's exactly what I was going for. Thanks

Comment: If you don't know what you want to do, it will be hard to help you do it.

Comment: Thanks, missed your previous message. Works great. Thanks

Comment: So that is what you wanted to do?

Comment: Yeah... English is a second language, my explanation was probably rubbish. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a marker at each end of the path, do something like this:

```
  paths['' + start + '_to_' + end].setOptions({
      map: map
  });
  // first point of polyline
  createMarker(paths['' + start + '_to_' + end].getPath().getAt(0), 'start', 'start', 'green'); 
  // last point of polyline
  createMarker(paths['' + start + '_to_' + end].getPath().getAt(paths['' + start + '_to_' + end].getPath().getLength()-1), 'end', 'end', 'red');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PwFDM/7/)